# Keras model unable to predict new samples with TFRecordDataset as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a Keras model using a TFRecordDataset iterator as input. The training phase works well but when I call `model.predict` the model is still using the training data as input instead of the new data.

```
# Load data as tensorflow iterator on a TFRecordDataset
X, y = loader.load_training_tensor_iterator()
X_test, y_test = loader.load_test_tensor_iterator()

# Build the model
input_layer = Input(tensor=X)
reshape = Flatten(input_shape=(-1, 10, 128))(input_layer)
a1 = Dense((200))(reshape)
a1 = BatchNormalization()(a1)
a1 = Activation('relu')(a1)
a1 = Dropout(drop_rate)(a1)
output_layer = Dense(classes_num, activation='sigmoid')(a1)
model  = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  target_tensors=[y])

model.fit(
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(TRAINING_SET_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE))
```

Now, when I try to use the model and get predictions for the test data:

```
# Run predictions
y_pred = model.predict(X_test, steps=3)
```

What I get in `y_pred` are predictions for the training set `X`, not those for `X_test`.

How can I specify that, when predicting, the input tensor should be the data passed to `predict` and not the tensor `X` passed in `Input(tensor=X)` ?

Comment: tf.keras.Model.predict accepts a tf.data Dataset or dataset iterator as input for prediction. Have you validated that `loader.load_test_tensor_iterator()` actually gives you the test data you expect?

Comment: Yes, the result from `load_test_tensor_iterator` is properly tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) for the Input layer and the [compile](https://keras.io/models/model/) method. When you set the tensor argument, Keras does not create a placeholder for input, which is the reason why you are unable to run the predict on X_test. You can feed to the model without setting the tensors option in the Input layer or the compile method and train your model and that will enable you to run predict, or evaluate with other variables by feeding to the placeholder.
[Here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_dataset_api.py) is an example showing testing by defining that way with dataset API from Keras.

Comment: The [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_dataset_api.py) finally put me in the right direction. They key was saving the model weights and restoring them later in a model using the X_test tensor as input

Comment: @jaime thats good to know! One thing that you might need to watch out for with this method though is whether the model accepts only a fixed batch size which corresponds to what you used for training. Have you tested your code with different batch size for the test data compared to the train data?

Comment: All these links are dead, can anyone comment on what the correct strategy was?

Comment: @bw4sz its been a while so I'm not exactly recalling what was in the last link! 
Basically the problem arises if you set the target_tensors option in compile method and the tensor in the input method as far as I remember. When doing so, Keras does not create any placeholders so the same tensors that were used in definition end up in the graph. If you see the example for Input layer, they have passed the shape but not set a tensor while this code explicitly sets a tensor.

Comment: Thanks @kvish. That makes sense. Working on a similar problem.